# Is it ok to ask something like "What is the Chinese name of this title bar component in the WeChat mini program?"?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, I was asked to develop a [WeChat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WeChat) mini program. But I found the English community of the WeChat mini program seems small.

I found the currently biggest problem is that, I don't know the Chinese name of the UI components, which the Chinese name may be helpful to search related documents in Chinese WeChat community.

Is it ok to screen shot something, and then ask something like: "What is the Chinese name of this title bar component?"?

addition note: the question that would like to ask is some question like (link to stackoverflow question:)

[What is the name of this Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254987/what-is-the-name-of-this-button)

[What's the name of this Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567544/whats-the-name-of-this-button)

[Android - What is the name of this kind of effect on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660411/android-what-is-the-name-of-this-kind-of-effect-on-android)

but in wechat UI, and I don't know the official name of the UI currently, and would also like to know the name of the UI both in English and Chinese.

Comment: No, that clearly has nothing to do with writing the code. If you want to know what it's like to experience the UI in Chinese, the best way is to *actually do so*. Otherwise, consider reading documentation for the program. But either way, you are clearly looking for help with *the WeChat program*, not with any programming language. This is so clearly off topic, per the guidelines [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), that it doesn't merit a fully written-up answer here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it seems that people can develop WeChat Mini Programs that can be used inside WeChat so this might in fact be related to programming. I don't know whether the question OP wants to ask is on-topic though, I'd lean on the side of off-topic since it almost sounds like a translation request.

Comment: I don't think example of a question is adequate for local on-topic requirements. But requests of official documentation are on-topic here, so if you'll ask question with screenshot and description what you already know, and ask for help in locating official documentation (and subsequently official name), your question shouldn't be closed. Thought it's not guaranteed that it will be well received.

Comment: there are many ways to get the name of it. For example, you can use google translate directly. I tried to translate a few components' name and they are all correct(textbox(文本框), Message Box(消息框), title bar(标题栏))

Answer (score 1):

You can ask at the [Chinese Language Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/).

Generally we expect that you provide reasonable context for your question, like a guess or a machine translation, as well as some indication as to why you find those to be insufficient or dubious.